# Must declare the scalar variable "@Image". error when saving image to database

Tags: asp.net, sql, image, save

I am currently trying to save an image to my database using this code:

```
byte[] myimage = new byte[FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength];
HttpPostedFile Image = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
Image.InputStream.Read(myimage, 0, (int)FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength);

string id = txtScanId.Text;

cmd1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TABLE(AssetImage) VALUES (@Image)";
cmd1.Connection = con1;
con1.Open();
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But I am getting the error:

> *Must declare the scalar variable "@Image"*

Can anyone help, I have been doing this for 6 hours!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declare a parameter but you have not supplied a value on it. In order to execute the code properly, set a value on the parameter before calling `ExecuteNonQuery()`.

```
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", myimage);
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: YES!! THANKS God i have been drilling away at this for hours, and now it finally saved to the database! Thanks so much :) i will be sure to one up your answer when the 10 minute timer expires!

Comment: you're welcome `:D`. hey for proper handling of object disposal, use `using` statement.

Comment: hey i have another problem, i have followed a tutorial 'explaining' how to read the data into an image. But i get this error when doing so: 'Object reference must be set to an instance of an object' I am using this code in a generic handler. http://codepad.org/d3Yd702T I get the error message on line 18. And in addition, in this tutorial; it states to put this line at the top of the aspx page. But in doing so it renders another error. <%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Handler" %>

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the below code hope it will work

```
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image",DbType.VARBINARY).Value= myimage;
```